# Ordering excel sheet columns in datagridview using combobox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm loading excel sheet into a data grid view and making some processes on it but   the data most be ordered in special way .
I'm looking for a way to order the column using combo box  that shows all column header to allow user to order data right way
thanks

Answer (score 0):

For using combobox to display column headers and sort column headers, you could try the following code.

```
public DataTable READExcel(string path)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objXL = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objWB = null;
    objXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Open(path);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objSHT = objWB.Worksheets[1];

    int rows = objSHT.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
    int cols = objSHT.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    int noofrow = 1;

    for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
    {
        string colname = objSHT.Cells[1, c].Text;
        dt.Columns.Add(colname);
        noofrow = 2;
    }

    for (int r = noofrow; r <= rows; r++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
        {
          dr[c - 1] = objSHT.Cells[r, c].Text;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    objWB.Close();
    objXL.Quit();
    return dt;
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = READExcel(@"C:\\...\\product.xlsx");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
       comboBox1.Items.Add(dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name);
    }
    comboBox1.Sorted = true;
}
```

The result:
[image]